# Linux tomcat + Windows Auth

Tags: linux, tomcat, windows-authentication

The requirements are -

1. The hosting application is Linux.
2. Windows authentication against a domain
3. Preferably using kerberos or the best security protocol

Tomcat is not really the requirement but a preferable choice.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to configure Tomcat JNDIRealm to use Microsoft Active Directory. Here's a link to the Tomcat JNDIRealm how-to: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JNDIRealm and here's a sample configuration: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/JNDI_HowTo.